# necessary condition of improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Does a function's limit when x goes to infinity must be zero for its integral to converge?

I had proved in my homework that if the function is non-negative, it's not necessarily true. 
Now I read a solution that uses this as a fact - For an improper integral to converge, function's limit must be zero.

I hadn't found it in my books and notebook, and I can't find a reliable place says it is.

any help would be appreciate, 
thanks

Comment: No. Think of "spikes" of height $1$, centered at the positive integers, the length of whose bases go to $0$ sufficiently fast to force the integral to converge.

Comment: Even easier examples abound for non-continuous functions.

Comment: No but if the improper integral converges and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102678/is-there-a-continuous-positive-function-whose-integral-over-0-infty-converg

Answer (score 9):

> For an improper integral to converge, function's limit must be zero.

That is correct only if we know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists. A nonzero value of this limit (say, $L$) would make the antiderivative $F$ grow at linear rate ($\sim Lx$) which is  not compatible with $F$ having a limit at infinity.

But it may well be that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ fails to exist but the integral $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges. A popular example, described by David Mitra in a comment, looks like this:

[image: spikes]

Comment: Is there a proof for the above fact? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is a counterexample:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x^2/2)\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2.
\end{equation}

Jog