# Calculate the integral of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I would like please to ask. 
How to prove that The integral of $e^{x^2}$, from $0$ to $\infty$, is divergent. Shall I use Maclaurin series for the exponential?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @coreyman317 I think you are thinking of $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your meaning, but the function $e^{x^2}$ increases (rapidly!) from $x=0$ to infinity.  Since $e^0=1$ the function is bounded below by $1$, and so the integral from zero to infinity will diverge (just as the integral of $1$ on the semi-infinite interval will increase without limit).  I don't think you need the Maclaurin series here.

Comment: See [this introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here.

Comment: $e^{x^2} \ge 1$

Answer (score 2):

The function $e^{x^{2}}$ is continuous increasing on $[0, \infty]$. Take
$$F(t) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{x^{2}}dx.$$
In each compact interval $[0,a]$, $e^{x^{2}}$ attains a minimum $m_{a}$. If $m_{a_{n}} \leq e^{x^{2}}$, then $m_{a_{n}}a_{n} \leq F(a_{n})$ on $[0,a_{n}]$. Also,
$$\infty = \lim_{n \to \infty}m_{a_{n}}a_{n} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}F(a_{n})$$

Answer (score 0):

For an integral to be convergent:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=I$$
where $I$ is a real number. We need the function to decrease such that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$
however for this function,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^2}\to\infty$$
so the integral cannot converge

Comment: why the downvote? seems correct

Comment: I did not downvote, but Henry's claim that $$ \int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty \implies \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$$ is not true. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643939/necessary-condition-of-improper-integral for a counterexample.

Comment: I appreciate that it is not true in all cases but it is definitely a good guide at least